# Show javascript datepicker on icon click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Its working when i click on `textbox` but i also want it on `icon click`.

Can anyone help me out please ?

*My source code is* :-

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
    <div class='input-group date'>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtfirstDeliverableDt" runat="server" Text="--please Select date--" CssClass="form-control deliverableTextbox date-picker" ></asp:TextBox>
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="datetimepicker1">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This would be your java script code:-**

```
$('.open-datetimepicker').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$('#datetimepicker').click();
 });
```

**Your html code would be like this:-**

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" id="datetimepicker" class="form-control" name="date">
<label class="input-group-addon btn" for="date">
   <span class="fa fa-calendar open-datetimepicker"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: ,i tried this but this is not working on icon click,but thank  a lot for your help sir